# What is the meaning of detail argument in Django ViewSet?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I create a custom action method in Django ViewSet and I see  [detail argument](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing). If I set `detail=True` I can't call this method from URL but if I set `detail=False`, I can call this method. May I know what is the meaning of detail argument?

Here is my viewset = >

```
class TimeSheetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet): 
    queryset = TimeSheet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TimeSheetSerializer

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=True)
    def byhello(self, request):        
        return Response({"From Hello":"Got it"})
```

Here are router and URL patterns =>

```
router.register('timesheets_ts', TimeSheetViewSet, base_name='timesheets')

urlpatterns = [   
    path('api/', include(router.urls))  
]
```

Answer (score 21):

As the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) states, if you pass `detail=True` it means that that router will return you a single object whilst if you don't pass `detail=True` or pass `detail=False` it will return a list of objects.

One thing to have in mind is that if you are not doing anything or don’t need a single object in this function, you can set the `detail=False`

In your case it’d be something like:

```
@action(methods=['get'], detail=True)
def byhello(self, request, pk=None):
    self.object = self.get_object()        
    return Response({"From Hello":"Got it"})
```

Comment: Thanks, I am new in web. According to my sample method, this is return single object, right? So it should be can call from url, right? why can't?

Comment: It's hard to say why it's not working because I can't see your code. Please, post your URLs and also your whole ViewSet. One thing I can tell is, you'd be able to access in the same URL your viewset is accessible but you can pass the method to be called. E.g `localhost:8000/api/users/1/byhello` There's this example on the link I provided on my answer.